# In a React-Redux App - after clicking menu item of MaterialUI menu, menu item list moves to the left of the page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I have an appbar containing two menus. On clicking any of the menu items of either menus, the menu list is shifted to the left of the page when the new page renders.

My appbar code is as following :

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  logo: {
    maxHeight: '80px',
    maxWidth: '100px'
  },
  logoContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  contentBase: {
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
    width: `100%`
  },
  contentRoot: {
    zIndex: 1,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    position: 'relative',
    display: 'flex',
    width: '100%',
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    marginRight: 'auto',
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    marginTop: '40px'
  }
})

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {  
  return {
    user: state.users['xyz@gmail.com'],
    auth: state.users.auth,
    profileMenuAnchorEl: state.ui.profileMenuAnchorEl,
    daoMenuAnchorEl: state.ui.daoMenuAnchorEl
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    getUser: email => {
      return dispatch(getUser(email))
    },
    handleNewProposalClick: () => {
      dispatch(resetNewProposal())
      ownProps.history.push('/proposals/new')  
    },
    handleProfileMenu: (event) => {
      dispatch(handleProfileMenu(event.currentTarget))
    },
    handleCloseProfileMenu: () => {
      dispatch(handleProfileMenu(null))
    },
    handleDaoMenu: (event) => {
      dispatch(handleDaoMenu(event.currentTarget))
    },
    handleCloseDaoMenu: () => {
      dispatch(handleDaoMenu(null))
    }
  }
}

const LayoutHOC = Page => class Layout extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    // TODO : Remove hard coding
    this.props.getUser('xyz@gmail.com')
  }
  
  render () {
    
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <div className={this.props.classes.logoContainer}>
              <img src={logoImage} className={this.props.classes.logo} alt='Test' />  
            </div>
            
            <Typography>
              SEM Balance: <b>{this.props.user ? this.props.user.sem: ''}</b>
            </Typography>
            &nbsp;
            <Typography>
              REP Balance: <b>{this.props.user ? this.props.user.rep: ''}</b>
            </Typography>

            <Button
              aria-owns={Boolean(this.props.daoMenuAnchorEl) ? 'render-props-menu' : null}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={this.props.handleDaoMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
            <ListIcon />
              DAOS
            </Button>
            <Menu 
              id="render-props-menu" 
              anchorEl={this.props.daoMenuAnchorEl}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(this.props.daoMenuAnchorEl)} 
              onClose={this.props.handleCloseDaoMenu}>
              <MenuItem onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/daos')}>Daos</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/proposals')}>Proposals</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
              
            <Button color='inherit'
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.handleNewProposalClick()
              }}
            >
              <AddIcon />
              New Proposal
            </Button>
            { this.props.auth && (
              <div>
                <IconButton
                  aria-owns={ Boolean(this.props.profileMenuAnchorEl) ? 'menu-appbar' : null}
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  onClick={this.props.handleProfileMenu}
                  color="inherit"
                >
                  <AccountCircle />
                </IconButton>
                <Menu
                  id="menu-appbar"
                  anchorEl={this.props.profileMenuAnchorEl}
                  anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'right',
                  }}
                  open={ Boolean(this.props.profileMenuAnchorEl) }
                  onClose={this.props.handleCloseProfileMenu}
                >
                  <MenuItem onClick={() => this.props.history.push(`/users/${this.props.user.email}`)} >Profile</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem onClick={this.props.handleCloseProfileMenu} >My account</MenuItem>
                </Menu>
              </div>
            )}
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <div className={this.props.classes.contentBase}>
          <div className={this.props.classes.contentRoot}>
            <div className={this.props.classes.content}>
              <Page {...this.props} /> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Page => withStyles(styles)(AppWrapper(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LayoutHOC(Page))
))
```

When I was using only one menu in the appbar, I did not face this issue.
I am using Menu, MenuItem, Button etc from MaterialUI. When the new page is rendered, why is my menu moving to the left?
What am I missing?

Comment: Please share codesandbox

Comment: Entire code can be found at https://github.com/dhiraka/semada-demo

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4om11xw1l

Comment: Ok. I’m looking into it

Answer (score 0):

You need place open prop of Menu in state as you can re-render component, you don't need redux for this. And you were not toggling open state `onClose`. Here is working codesandbox :
[Menu Anchor Fixed](https://codesandbox.io/s/y0konyy3v1)

Comment: The codesandbox is not working